# Adding a class to a list element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add an active class to a list element and cannot work out why this method isn't working Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Please see my code below.

Here's the HTML

```
<ul class="Menu">
<li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab1','tab1text')">Menu Item</a></li>
<li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab2','tab2text')">Menu item</a></li>
<li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab3','tab3text')">Menu Item</a></li>
<li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab4','tab4text')">Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

And CSS with the classes

```
.tab {
color:;
background-color:;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
} 

.active {
color: #00ffff;
}
```

And the Javascript function

```
<script>
function showContent(obj, content, text)
obj.className += " active";
</script>
```

Here is a JSfiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/wxjop98f/1/

I can't work out why this doesn't work as various tutorials state this method. Many thanks for any help provided.

Comment: You seem to have created a function but there's nothing calling it, we don't know what's being passed in. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Serg Chernata the onclick handler calls it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several problems:

1. You need to make sure that the javascript block in jsfiddle is loaded in the `<head>` (no wrap)
   [image]
2. The function block should be wrapped in `{...}`
3. It's better to use `obj.classList.add` (although `obj.className += ' active'` will work too.
4. If you want the color on the `.active` to work on the `<a>` elements you should use `a.active` (otherwise the `anchor`'s color definition will get higher priority).

Here is the fix:
https://jsfiddle.net/54w6ntx7/

And a complete snippet:

```js
function showContent(obj, content, text) {
  //debugger;
  obj.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
a:link{
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
a:visited{
  color: inherit;
}
a:active{
  color: inherit;
}

.tab {
  color:;
  background-color:;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
} 

a.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Menu">
 <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab1','tab1text')">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab2','tab2text')">Menu item</a></li>
    <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab3','tab3text')">Menu Item</a></li>
 <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="showContent(this,'tab4','tab4text')">Menu Item</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: 4. was actually biggest problem in this case, plus one.

Comment: @sinisake all of those together caused the problem. Each one of them alone weren't good enough to fix it :) Thanks for the vote!

Comment: proper code loading (i guess that OP's script is inside body, so that's fiddle problem) and a.active, and: https://jsfiddle.net/dy9bea61/ :) Not sure, but somehow - js engine 'knew' what to do?

Comment: Point #1 is related specifically to jsfiddle. However - even if the OP's script is inside the `body` tag - the code itself has a syntax error. #3 is nice-to-have, and #4 is required :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes it was the 'a.' I was missing as I had toe curly brackets in the original code and forgot to copy them over.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the {} for your function:

```
function showContent(obj, content, text){
    obj.className += " active";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/wxjop98f/4/

Comment: I'm afraid this is not enough. You can read my answer for more details :)

Comment: I think you will find my jsfiddle does what the OP asked. Yes you have debugged further his code, but the question he asked has been answered.

Comment: In your jsfiddle the links are not turned green after clicked on.

Comment: Again, my jsfiddle addresses the problematic part of the code. You have assumed that he is having problems with the color in the css though its not mentioned. Adding the active class is all he asks about. I concede your answer addresses more issues, but that does not mean that mine does not answer the actual question.

Comment: The reason for adding the `.active` class was to change the color :-) even if the OP didn't write it in the question, it's pretty clear from the code.

Comment: That may well be the case, but adding a color property is clearly not where he is struggling. He was asking about adding the class to the element. Once he has that working he can do what he likes. I have answered the question, you have answered and some more, thats fine, I dont know why you are trolling me.

Comment: Not trolling, but I advise you to check the OP's comment in my answer.

Comment: Wow, you really are trying my patience. The question reads: "I am trying to add an active class to a list element and cannot work out why this method isn't working". I have shown how to make that method work. The OP has admitted that he copied and pasted his code incorrectly. Given the question he asked and the code he pasted I have answered the question correctly. Perhaps your time would be better spent clarifying how to ask the right questions, rather than criticizing the right answers to the wrong questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your javascript as follows, you just missed curly braces

```
<script>
function showContent(obj, content, text)
{
obj.className = "active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the other answers before posting this one?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showContent(obj, content, text) {
  if (obj.className.indexOf("active") < 0)
    obj.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
  color: ;
  background-color: ;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.active {
  color: #00ffff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Menu">
  <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showContent(this,'tab1','tab1text')">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showContent(this,'tab2','tab2text')">Menu item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showContent(this,'tab3','tab3text')">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab" style=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showContent(this,'tab4','tab4text')">Menu Item</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put onclick function in anchor tag `<a>` and you are putting active class on `<a>` so please put onclick function on `<li>` tag instead of `<a>`.